# Builds stuck after upgrading to .NET8 and Visual Studio 17.8

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2022

I recently made three changes to my local development environment in succession:

1. I upgraded VS2022 from 17.6 to 17.7.
2. Next I installed the .NET8 SDK.  After this, VS2022 offers the upgrade to 17.8.
3. I upgraded VS2022 to 17.8.

My main reason for completing this upgrade path was to make use of a new project template that's only available in VS2022 17.8.  I started a new project  based on that template and built out some things targeting .NET8.  So far no issues there.

Afterward I needed to switch to a different app that has multiple projects in the solution targeting .NET6.  This app has been in development for almost a year and using .NET6 the entire time.  When I tried to rebuild the solution, I hangs...

[image]

I looked in Windows Settings -> Apps and found that .NET8 SDK listed but .NET6 no longer was.  It's unclear to me whether .NET8 is an upgrade to 6.  I went ahead and reinstalled the .NET6 SDK just in case my VS solution requires it to be a stand-alone SDK on disk.  The problem persisted.  Rebuilding, building, or attempting to launch in debug mode, it hangs.

At least I thought it was hanging.  Another thread explained how to enable diagnostic level logging for MSBuild.  I modified a WebAPI project's properties to do that, and now I see this:

```
Rebuild started at 11:54 AM...
Restoring NuGet packages...
To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the NuGet Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
Running restore with 16 concurrent jobs.
Reading project file C:\devops\***.ArcGisRest.csproj.
Reading project file C:\devops\***.FunctionApp.csproj.
Reading project file C:\devops\***.Api.csproj.
Reading project file C:\devops\***.Api.Tests.csproj.
Reading project file C:\devops\***.Data.csproj.
Restoring packages for C:\devops\***.FunctionApp.csproj...
Restoring packages for C:\devops\***.Api.csproj...
Restoring packages for C:\devops\***.ArcGisRest.csproj...
Reading project file C:\devops\***.Core.csproj.
Restoring packages for C:\devops\***.Data.csproj...
Restoring packages for C:\devops\***.Core.csproj...
Restoring packages for C:\devops\***.Api.Tests.csproj...
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0...
Resolving conflicts for net6.0...
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0...
Resolving conflicts for net6.0...
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0...
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0...
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/vulnerabilities/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/vulnerabilities/vulnerability.base.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/vulnerabilities/vulnerability.update.json
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0...
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0...
Resolving conflicts for net6.0...
Resolving conflicts for net6.0...
Resolving conflicts for net6.0...
Resolving conflicts for net6.0...
NuGet package restore failed. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ***.ArcGisRest, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ***.Core, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ***, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
```

The full diagnostic output is way too big to paste all of it.

It takes several minutes for this process to complete, so after code changes I'm waiting that long to launch in debug mode again.  It's untenable.

Have a screwed myself by upgrading to .NET8 SDK?  Curious what other config changes I may need to make to get past this?

Update 1:
These are the only warnings I can see in the Error List window that pertain to the NuGet restore failures.

[image]

Update 2:
The problem turned out to be a NuGet package source that's hosted on the company network.  I didn't even realize it was configured in VS2022.  All of the problem documented above are happening while WFH, so this package source isn't accessible.  It's caused a whole host of problems that were very difficult to diagnose.  The clue was in the second screenshot which shows the local IPs of the proprietary package source.  I disabled it for now and my project is building normally again.
[image]

Comment: So there is `NuGet package restore failed.` error. Have you tried to fix this error?

Comment: Regarding the NuGet package restore failure, it says to check the Error List window, but there are no errors listed and the only warnings that sound similar are now pasted into my original post.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about why would it restore package since you were previously building fine. So I assume they were not missing. Have you tried keeping your package source ticked and disable automatic check for missing packages as the logging suggests?

Comment: I have not tried that but I may just out of curiosity.  This entire problem had nothing to do with the upgrades from .NET6 to .NET8 or the VS2022 version upgrades.  It was just a coincidence that I did those things and then worked from home the next day.

Answer (score 1):

Stalled builds can sometimes be a result of not having access to a package source.

The best way to triage stalled builds is to run open Powershell (or another CLI) and run the command
`dotnet build --verbosity diagnostic` which gives the most detailed results.

Below is how I diagnosed my problem. I'm leaving this answer for those who come after.

---

I had a similar issue. In this case the `dotnet build` command was stuck on

```
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0... (TaskId:37)
Resolving conflicts for net8.0... (TaskId:37)
```

From that I understood that packages weren't being restored and checked my package sources. I found that my local NuGet folder, located in `C:\Users\%username%\.nuget\packages` was missing some of the packages in my solution. The specific packages were ones from an internal NuGet source.

Once I was able to connect to the internal network I could download the packages and the build succeeded.